# Draw animated image in TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I want to draw an animated image in TextBox, i Google my problem, but i get some examples about drawing a fixed image in TextBox like [ExtRichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/MyExtRichTextBox.aspx).

Comment: What kind of TextBox? Windows Forms? WPF? Silverlight? WebForms?

Comment: I want to use it in Windows Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you can draw a fixed image as you say then animating it is simply a matter of changing that fixed image on some interval.  I assume you can already do the fixed image bit, so simply setup a timer that will redraw the image using a new frame on some interval.

```
private void SomeTimer_Tick( ... )
{
    UpdateAnimation();
}

private int _frameCount;
private const int MaxFrames = //whatever, you need to determine this
private void UpdateAnimation()
{
    _frameCount = (_frameCount + 1) % MaxFrames;
    var image = GetFrame( _frameCount );
    // draw the new frame 
}

private const int FrameWidth = // again, you need to determine this
private const int FrameHeight = // again, you need to determine this
private Bitmap GetFrame( int frame )
{
    // assumes frames are lined up horizontally on a sheet
    var rect = new Rectangle( frame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight );

    // you could create the frames up front to avoid many calls to Clone()
    return MySpriteSheet.Clone( rect, MySpriteSheet.PixelFormat );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but isn't there other way to draw animated image ?! because i want to use it in an environment like yahoo messenger conversation form. And the number of images aren't just one.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  Of course the number of frames is > 1, otherwise it wouldn't be an animation.  Typically you would have a single image that contains each frame of the animation and then selectively grab frames from it as I do in my example.  In WPF there are animation classes available which can make things a bit easier, but setting up a timer to change the image on some interval is trivial.

Comment: Suggest that we have some gif format images, so, we want to replace them instead of some string like :) or :| and etc ( like the work that messengers conversation form do ). Now, i want to do a work like this in C# environment. What's your reason to do that ?!